# Write a cordova plugin to run right after an Android app starts

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I would like to know how to write a Cordova plugin for Android that runs some code right after an app starts. For iOS plugins, I can do the following:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
do stuff
```

And the AppDelegate will run when the applications starts.

What about for Android plugins. If I do the following, will it run when the app starts?

```
public class AppDelegate extends CordovaPlugin {
  @Override
  public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    //custom code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've dealt with this in the past and the way some of the Apache Cordova plugins do this is to hook in to the `onCordovaReady` event from Cordova in your plugin's JS code.

```
var channel = require('cordova/channel');

channel.onCordovaReady.subscribe(function() {
    //Call your plugin and do whatever you need to do with the results of it
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Device", "getDeviceInfo", []);
});
```